# How to match all possible paths through multiple relationship types with filtering (Neo4j, Cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and I have a relatively complex (but small) database which I have simplified to the following:
 [image: room/door/window example]

The first door has no key, all other doors have keys, the window doesn't require a key. The idea is that if a person has `key:'A'`, I want to see all possible paths they could take.

Here is the code to generate the db

```
CREATE (r1:room {name:'room1'})-[:DOOR]->(r2:room {name:'room2'})-[:DOOR {key:'A'}]->(r3:room {name:'room3'})
CREATE (r2)-[:DOOR {key:'B'}]->(r4:room {name:'room4'})-[:DOOR {key:'A'}]->(r5:room {name:'room5'})
CREATE (r4)-[:DOOR {key:'C'}]->(r6:room {name:'room6'})
CREATE (r2)-[:WINDOW]->(r4)
```

Here is the query I have tried, expecting it to return everything except for `room6`, instead I have an error which means I really don't know how to construct the query.

```
with {key:'A'} as params
match (n:room {name:'room1'})-[r:DOOR*:WINDOW*]->(m)
where r.key=params.key or not exists(r.key)
return n,m
```

To be clear, I don't need my query debugged so much as help understanding how to write it correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
WITH  {key:'A'} AS params
MATCH p=(n:room {name:'room1'})-[:DOOR|WINDOW*]->(m)
WHERE ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE NOT EXISTS(r.key) OR r.key=params.key)
RETURN n, m
```

With your sample data, the result is:

```
╒════════════════╤════════════════╕
│"n"             │"m"             │
╞════════════════╪════════════════╡
│{"name":"room1"}│{"name":"room2"}│
├────────────────┼────────────────┤
│{"name":"room1"}│{"name":"room3"}│
├────────────────┼────────────────┤
│{"name":"room1"}│{"name":"room4"}│
├────────────────┼────────────────┤
│{"name":"room1"}│{"name":"room5"}│
└────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I needed. I suspected `any()` or `all()` would come into it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, would it be considered better form to explicitly have the `key:null` property in each relationship, for completeness? (no-schema db is still very foreign to me)